# Replacing characters from string one to string two

Tags: python

I need to create a function that takes the parameters (character, stringOne, stringTwo). The function returns a new word  which contain the same data as stringTwo + whatever characters in stringOne in the same position.

Example:

- stringOne = "apple"
- stringTwo = "12345"
- character = "p"
- Should Return "1pp45"

I am lost on how I should proceed.

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
newWord = ""
for s in range(len(word1)):
    if word1[s] == char:
return
```

Comment: You should fix the indentation of your code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to modify your existing code so that it does what you want. I've changed `newWord` to `new_word` to conform with the standard Python style convention.

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    new_word = ""
    for i in range(len(word2)):
        if word1[i] == char:
            new_word += char
        else:
            new_word += word2[i]
    return new_word

# Test
print(replace("p", "apple", "12345"))
```

**output**

```
1pp45
```

Note that this code will raise an `IndexError: string index out of range` exception if `word1` is shorter than `word2`.

There are various better ways to implement this function. Firstly, we can use the `zip` function to iterate over the characters of both strings in parallel. This is a bit cleaner than your indirect iteration using the indices of the strings to access the characters.

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    new_word = ""
    for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2):
        if c1 == char:
            new_word += char
        else:
            new_word += c2
    return new_word
```

Note that if the strings aren't the same length then `zip` will stop gracefully when the shorter string finishes.

We can make that code more compact by replacing the `if... else` block with a conditional expression.

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    new_word = ""
    for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2):
        new_word += char if c1 == char else c2
    return new_word
```

---

A more advanced version uses a list comprehension to build a list of the desired characters and the string `.join` method to convert that list into a string.

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    return ''.join([char if c1 == char else c2 
        for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2)])
```

It's also possible to do this using a generator expression.

```
''.join(char if c1 == char else c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2))
```

However that's less efficient than using a list comprehension, due to the way that `.join` works. `.join` has to scan its argument twice: the first scan is used to calculate the total size of the output string, the second scan does the actual joining. But you can't scan a generator twice, so if you pass `.join` a generator it has to build a temporary list from the generator.

Answer (score 5):

Continuing what you have done, using simple `for-loop` and ternary operation, this is how it can be done:

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    newWord = ""
    for s in range(len(word1)):
        newWord += char if word1[s] == char else word2[s]
    return newWord
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    newWord = ""
    for s in range(len(word1)):
        if word1[s] == char:
            newWord += char
        else:
            newWord += word2[s]
    return newWord
```

Just in case you are not familiar with ternary operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a list comprehension, iterate and replace.

```
>>> x, y, c = 'apple', '12345', 'p'              
>>> ''.join([c if x[i] == c else s for i, s in enumerate(y)])
'1pp45'
```

Comment: This is not the sort of code that I would show to someone struggling to learn to program.

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way:

```
>>> stringOne = "apple" 
>>> stringTwo = "12345"
>>> my_char = "p"
>>> "".join([x[1] if my_char!=x[0] else x[0] for x in zip(stringOne, stringTwo)])
'1pp45'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    newWord= list(word2)
    for counter in range(min(len(word1), len(word2))):
            if word1[counter]== char:
                    newWord[counter]= char
    return "".join(newWord)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to iterate through characters of word1 and if a character match is found with the character that we are interested in finding, then we replace the character at that index in word2.

```
def replace(char, word1, word2):
    newWord = ""
    word2List = list(word2)
    # Check is character is present in word1
    # and if length of word1 and word2 are equal
    if char not in word1 or len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False
    else:
        for i,c in enumerate(word1):
            if c == char:
                word2List[i] = c



    # Converting list back to string
    return ''.join(word2List)

print(replace('p','apple','12345'))
```

Output:

```
1pp45
```